# What is an adjective to describe something that creates questions and thought

Tags: single-word-requests

Words like "questionable" don't fit because they relay the wrong information. Using "questionable" could state that the noun itself is out of place when I want the reader to interpret that the noun is being described.

"Don't create _______ movie scenes if you're unable to answer them later."
or
"Don't create television scenes that produce questions if you're unable to answer them later."

Comment: 'thought-provoking' is one but that doesn't fit with 'answer'

Comment: "Don't create scenes that raise questions if you are unable to answer them later"

Answer (score 2):

***Enigmatic***, perhaps.

*Enigmatic* - ambiguous, obscure, perplexing (OED).

*"Don't create **enigmatic** movie scenes if you're unable to answer (explain) them later."*

Answer (score 1):

Although imperfect, 'cryptic' seems to work, provided you change the associated verb:

> "Don't create *cryptic* movie scenes if you're unable to *unravel* them later."

Answer (score 0):

For an adjective that means it's something that generates questions, rather than something that is *dubious* (another sense of *questionable*), use [**interrogative**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interrogative):

> **1 a** : used in a question
> **1 b** : having the form or force of a question
> **2 :** inquisitive, questioning
>
> // The movie’s superficiality perhaps embodies what Bradbury was trying to say—that TV and film are stunted, two-dimensional forms of entertainment compared to the complexity, the richness, and the *interrogative* nature of books.
> — Sophie Gilbert, *The Atlantic*, "Fahrenheit 451 Tackles the Evils of Social Media," 19 May 2018

As in:

> Don't create *interrogative* movies scenes if you're unable to answer them later.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create ***[open-ended](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/open-ended)*** movie situations if you're unable to resolve them later.

Or, you might like *question provoking*.